# Insert Row and Copy Row Above with different values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some VBA that does two things:

1. When a value J column = "XY" duplicate the row by inserting the same data into a row below
2. In the newly inserted row, change values in G, H & L to "0"

So far, I have found this, which works to insert a blank row but I cannot figure out how to do the rest:

```
Dim i As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set i = Range("J:J")
For Each cell In i.Cells
  If cell.Value = "XY" Then
  cell.EntireRow.Copy
    cell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
  End If
Next
```

The above inserts a blank row but I also need to copy and paste the row above its values and change some.

Comment: What code have you tried adding to it so far? Where did you run into trouble with it? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have tried to add a copy row instruction such as this:

Dim i As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set i = Range("J:J")
For Each cell In i.Cells
If Cell.value = "XY" Then 
cell.EntireRow.Copy
Cell.offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
End if
Next

This didnt work and doesnt address the change of the value in the columns

Answer (score 0):

When inserting/deleting rows it's usually best to loop from the bottom up.

That's what the following, simple, example does.

```vb
Sub InsertXY()
Dim idx As Long

    For idx = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Range("J" & idx).Value = "XY" Then
            Rows(idx).Copy
            Rows(idx + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Intersect(Rows(idx + 1), Range("G:H, L:L")).Value = 0
        End If
    Next idx
    
End Sub
```

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!